# QGraphicsView shows artifacts after opening file dialog

Tags: qt, qgraphicsview, qimage, qpixmap

I'm not terribly familiar with Qt's memory model especially when it comes to image handling.  I'm created a blank pixmap and adding it to a QGraphicsView's scene.  This seems to work correctly jumping between two sizes, but I've noticed I get graphical artifacts calling this function if I open a QFileDialog ([before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dn97d.png) and [after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CK5iq.png)).  These artifacts are in the actual view as I can pan around and they stay present.  It doesn't seem to matter where on screen the QFileDialog pops up, I still get these issues.

Is there something I need to do to manually rerender that portion of the image or do I probably have more serious problems elsewhere in the code?

```
void RenderView::setViewport(int width, int height)
{
    if (_viewportOverlay != 0)
        scene()->removeItem(_viewportOverlay);

    const int BORDER = VIEWPORT_BORDER;
    QImage image(width+BORDER*2,height+BORDER*2, QImage::Format_ARGB32);
    QPixmap pixmap = QPixmap::fromImage(image);

    _viewportOverlay = scene()->addPixmap(pixmap);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Documentation for that `QImage` constructor says

> Warning: This will create a QImage with uninitialized data. Call
>   fill() to fill the image with an appropriate pixel value before
>   drawing onto it with QPainter.

so I'd suggest adding an `image.fill(0)` before doing anything with the pixmap.